# How can I disable spelling check for words contain multiple uppercase letters?

Tags: microsoft-word

e.g. "LaTex", "MathJax", etc.

Besides adding such words into custom dictionaries one by one.

Comment: Word's spelling checker does have an option for ALL UPPERCASE but not for mixed. Again, this is a user option, not a document setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is no Word setting that can do this.*

### You can, though, use a No Spell Check character style and apply it to the words.

*This is a setting that sticks with the word in the document regardless of which computer is used to open the document, unlike adding words to your spell check dictionary. Adding to your dictionary stops flagging on your computer only.*

Here is a macro to create such a character style:

```
Sub NoSpellCheckStyle()  ' SEE ALSO ASSIGNSHORTCUTNOSPELLCHECK FOLLOWING
    ' Charles Kenyon
    ' Creates a character style named "No Spell Check" in the Active Document
    ' Does NOT apply the style to a selection, simply creates the style
    ' 12 April 2019
    '
    Dim stlNoCheck As Style
    '
    On Error GoTo ErrorAlreadyExists
    Set stlNoCheck = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="No Spell Check", Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)
    On Error GoTo -1
    With stlNoCheck
        .Font.Name = ""
        .NoProofing = True
    End With
    GoTo ExitSub
ErrorAlreadyExists:
    MsgBox Prompt:="Style 'No Spell Check' already exists", Buttons:=vbInformation, title:="Oops"
ExitSub:
    Set stlNoCheck = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is a separate macro to assign a keyboard shortcut to the character style:

```
Sub AssignShortcutNoSpellCheck()
'
' Charles Kenyon ---- GOES WITH PREVIOUS MACRO
' 2 March 2021
' Assigns keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N to No Spell Check style
'   Style must exist
'   Saves this in the active document
'
    CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument ' Change ActiveDocument to NormalTemplate if style is in Normal Template
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyN, wdKeyControl, _
        wdKeyShift, wdKeyAlt), _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryStyle, _
        Command:="No Spell Check"
End Sub
```

You can change the keyboard shortcut to something else if you want.

Note that you can use `Ctrl`+`Spacebar` to return to the underlying paragraph style after using the character style.

With words that are already in your document, you would select the word and apply the character style.

When typing, you would turn on the character style and then type your Word, following with `Ctrl`+`Spacebar`.

Remember that the "do not check" attribute is an invisible formatting code and it acts much like **Bold** in that it continues in operation when you type, except that you cannot see it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Well, I do have some no-spell-check styles (code, etc). But applying style for "non-style" purpose seems not that appropriate. <@_@> Also, Word doesn't support stacked styles. To keep consistency, we need to create a no-spell-check version for each visible style.

Comment: Word does support character styles applied to text formatted with a paragraph style. The character style created by the macro only changes the spelling attribute of the text. If you are using direct formatting or another character style, then the formatting will return to that of the underlying paragraph style. Here is my chapter on styles: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Character.

Comment: Using a character style for language characteristics is an old use for character styles. This can also be used to set the proofing language for certain words. It is an appropriate use of a style. -- Using a no spell check style is the only way to assure that your words will not be flagged on someone else's computer.